# Doctrine Entity looping through another Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I currently have a Property entity which has a relationship with PropertyRates. I need to find out the latest a PropertyRate has been updated. Currently I have a function in the Property entity to loop the associated PropertyRates and return the latest PropertyRate->dateModified. This runs out of memory very quickly looping through thousands of Properties.

```
public function getRatesDateModified()
{
    $retval = new \DateTime("2000-01-01T06:00:00Z");
    foreach($this->propertyRates as $rate) {
        if($retval < $rate->getDateModified()) {
            $retval = $rate->getDateModified();
        }
    }

    return $retval;
}
```

Is this where this function should sit? It didn't seem right to put it in the repository as it is specific to a single entity, but without access to the EntityManager so I can detach the PropertyRates I run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using doctrine, might I suggest using the [filtering api](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). Maybe something like this.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$entity = $entityManager->find('Entity', $id);
$propertyRates = $entity->getPropertyRates();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->orderBy(["dateModified"]))
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(20);

$result = $userCollection->matching($criteria)[0];
```

Comment: Where is $group coming from? Also, where would this code be put? Where I currently call getRatesDateModified()?

Comment: It was a copy and paste example with modifications from the documentation. The $entity is supposed to be the entity that contains the collection of PropertyRates. I would recommend placing this code in a Repository.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it is the right way to do it, but it doesn't work for me like every part of Doctrine it throws some useless error. I'll use a DQL query in the Repo instead.